# Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2017 to stop trying to retrieve a package from both Nuget.org and a TFS 2017 feed?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, nuget

We have a couple of internal nuget packages in an on-premise TFS 2017 feed.  They are used by our internal applications only; however, when we are installing external nuget.org hosted packages, Visual Studio is trying to retrieve them from both the internal source and nuget.org and it is taking a lot of time to get a package installed.  Is there any way tell it to download from a specific server?

Here is an partial listing of me trying to install Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect in the package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -verbose
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.host.systemweb/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.host.systemweb/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.host.systemweb/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.host.systemweb/index.json 61ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.host.systemweb/index.json 60ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.host.systemweb/index.json 143ms
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.host.systemweb/index.json


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.4.0.0' with respect to project 'WebAppName.Web', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source NuGet official package source gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source nuget.org gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source Local Source gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source OurCustomFeed gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source OurCustomFeed Repo gathered from cache.
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/owin/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/owin/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/owin/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.security/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.security.cookies/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.security/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security.cookies/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security.cookies/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.security.cookies/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/owin/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.identitymodel.logging/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security/index.json 62ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/owin/index.json 64ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/owin/index.json 76ms
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.logging/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.logging/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt/index.json 41ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin/index.json 72ms
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security/index.json 93ms
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security.cookies/index.json 86ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security.cookies/index.json 93ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect/index.json 90ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin/index.json 99ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect/index.json 80ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt/index.json 76ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt/index.json 67ms
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.logging/index.json 67ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols/index.json 59ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/newtonsoft.json/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.logging/index.json 69ms
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/newtonsoft.json/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/newtonsoft.json/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocol.extensions/index.json
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocol.extensions/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols/index.json 64ms
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocol.extensions/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect/index.json 51ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/product.utilities/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens/index.json 64ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect/index.json 56ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens/index.json 54ms
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/product.utilities/index.json
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/newtonsoft.json/index.json 52ms
  NotFound http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/newtonsoft.json/index.json 51ms
  GET http://tfs.company.com/tfs/TfsRep/_packaging/18c3561d-f194-4914-90e2-9506ea56646c/nuget/v3/registrations2/product.utilities/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.owin.security/index.json

... Hundreds of more similiar calls ....
```

Note how every file involves a call to our company's TFS 2017 server (tfs.company.com) and then to the Nuget server (api.nuget.org).

Things I've tried:

- I thought this might have something to do with the nuget.config file that we have at the solution level, but I've removed it and this still happens.
- I've looked through the [nuget.config settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file).
- I've tried installing from the UI tool and only selecting Nuget.org
- I've searched Google and Stack Overflow for possible TFS Feed issues, but I can't seem to find anyone with this problem.

Other possibilities

- I'm not sure if upgrading our TFS server to TFS 2018 and using upstream source (TFS 2017 doesn't have nuget.org as a source) will fix this problem either since this seems to be related to the way Visual Studio gets and checks nuget sources.  We don't plan to do that till the 3rd quarter of this year, so I'd like to find a solution other than moving our feed out of TFS 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio is trying to retrieve them from both the internal source and nuget.org and it is taking a lot of time to get a package installed. Is there any way tell it to download from a specific server?

This is NuGet default behavior. When we install a NuGet package to the project, NuGet 3.0+ will send multitasking requests to the all NuGet sources, so that we could get feedback more efficiently.

That is the reason for the following requests in the output log:

```
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source NuGet official package source gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source nuget.org gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source Local Source gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source OurCustomFeed gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages gathered from cache.
Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from source OurCustomFeed Repo gathered from cache.
```

If you want to download from a specific server, you can specific a source to install this package by the [Parameters -Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-install-package#parameters):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -verbose -source nuget.org
```

In this case, we could retrieve the package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb only from the source `nuget.org` rather than detect all nuget package sources.

**However**, if the installed nuget package have dependencies, NuGet will detect all package sources when it attempt to gather dependency information. And this is also NuGet default behavior. We do not need to add all the dependencies packages to the custom feed when we install the nuget package.

The **current workaround** is that you can unavailable the TFS 2017 Feed when you install some specify packages(Uncheck the TFS 2017 package source).

For tracking the underlying NuGet issue, I open a thread on the [Github](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6899), you can check this thread for the latest feedback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Leo, we are also see extremely slow retrievals when retrieving a TFS 2017 Nuget package from an internal feed IF it has dependencies from NuGet.org.  Is there a way to tell TFS 2017, "hey, grab our package, but all the dependencies are on Nuget.org" or is this something that Upstream Feeds option in TFS 2018 is supposed to fix?

Comment: if you are slow retrievals when retrieving a TFS 2017 Nuget package from an internal feed IF it has dependencies from NuGet.org, you could also add the dependencies to the TFS 2017 feed and disable nuget.org source. And AFAIK, Upstream Feeds option in TFS 2018 only for source npmjs.com not nuget.org.

Comment: Leo, It is in TFS 2018 Update 2:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/nuget/upstream-sources?view=vsts
Unfortunately, we will not see this version till the 3rd quarter of this year when we update from TFS 2017 to 2018.